# Showing certain functions are random variables

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

> Assume $\{X_k\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$ are random variables on a probability space. Define induced random walk by $S_0 = 0$ and $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i$. Now let $n = \inf\{p > 0: S_p > 0\}$ be the first upgoing ladder time. We want to show $n$ is a random variable. Also if $\forall x \in \Omega $ (Sample Space), $x(n) < \infty$ then show $S_n$ is a random variable.

These seem to be multiple ways to show if some function is a random variable, I wasn't sure what exact defintions and techniques to use here. The approach I am thinking of is:

When $n = 1$ that implies $\{n = 1\} = \{X_1 > 0\}$. Then try other values for n and try generalize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if $A_1,A_2,\ldots$ are events and we define
$$
T(\omega)=\inf\{n\geq 1\mid \omega\in A_n\}\quad \left(\text{with } \inf\varnothing:=\infty\right)
$$
then
$$
\{T=n\}=A_1^c\cap \cdots\cap A_{n-1}^c\cap A_n.
$$

---

In this particular scenario we have that $A_n=\{S_n>0\}$ which is clearly a measurable set for all $n\geq 1$. Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\{T=n\}&=A_1^c\cap A_2^c\cap\cdots\cap A_{n-1}^c\cap A_n\\
&=\{S_1\leq 0\}\cap\{S_2\leq 0\}\cap\cdots\cap\{S_{n-1}\leq 0\}\cap\{S_n>0\}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Could you explain more on how knowing that helps us in this situation?

Comment: @user77404: See the edit. Try to think about it: If $n$ is the first time that $S_t$ becomes positive, then $S_t$ _must_ be non-positive at every time up till time $n$ and positive at time $n$.

Comment: The edit helps alot thanks, so this argument would show that both n and $S_n$ are random variables, or that just one of them is?

Comment: @user77404: For each fixed $n\geq 1$ we have that $S_n=X_1+\cdots +X_n$ is a random variable, since it is a sum of $n$ random variables. You should be familiar with such a result. That $S_n$ is a random variable implies in particular that $\{S_n\leq 0\}$ and $\{S_n>0\}$ are measurable sets. Since $\{T=n\}$ (for a fixed $n\geq 1$) can be written as the intersection of finitely many of such subsets, we have that $\{T=n\}$ itself is a measurable set. Since $\{T=n\}$ is measurable for each fixed $n\geq 1$, we have that $T$ is a random variable.